# I am not able to send data to all clients from a single server

Tags: sockets, tcp, fork, ipc

I am using a for loop on the server-side to send data to all clients received from a single client. But it is unable to send to all clients. Instead, it just sends data to the only client who has sent the data. And also it is not printing the **here** printf line on the server console.

```
for(int j=0;j<i;j++){ 
 printf("here");
 send(fds[j], buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
}
```

My server-side code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 9999

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    int sockfd, ret;
     struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;

    int newSocket;
    struct sockaddr_in newAddr;
    char lastchar = 'a';
    socklen_t addr_size;

    char buffer[1024];
    pid_t childpid;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd < 0){
        printf("[-]Error in connection.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("[+]Server Socket is created.\n");

    memset(&serverAddr, '\0', sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    ret = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    if(ret < 0){
        printf("[-]Error in binding.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("[+]Bind to port %d\n", 4444);

    if(listen(sockfd, 10) == 0){
        printf("[+]Listening....\n");
    }else{
        printf("[-]Error in binding.\n");
    }

    int fds[10];
    int i = 0;
    while(1){
        newSocket = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&newAddr, &addr_size);
        fds[i++] = newSocket;
        if(newSocket < 0){
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Connection accepted from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(newAddr.sin_addr), ntohs(newAddr.sin_port));
        
        if((childpid = fork()) == 0){
            close(sockfd);

            while(1){
                recv(newSocket, buffer, 1024, 0);
                
                if(strcmp(buffer, ":exit") == 0){
                    printf("Disconnected from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(newAddr.sin_addr), ntohs(newAddr.sin_port));
                    break;
                }else{

                    if(buffer[0]==lastchar){
                        lastchar = buffer[strlen(buffer)-1];
                        bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                        strcpy(buffer, "Correct!");
                    }else{          
                        bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                        strcpy(buffer, "Wrong!");
                         
                    }
                    
                    for(int j=0;j<i;j++){ 
                        printf("here");
                        send(fds[j], buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
                    }
                    
                    bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                }
            }
        }

    }

    close(newSocket);


    return 0;
}
```

My Client-side code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 9999

int main(){

    int clientSocket, ret;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    char buffer[1024];

    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(clientSocket < 0){
        printf("[-]Error in connection.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("[+]Client Socket is created.\n");

    memset(&serverAddr, '\0', sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    ret = connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    if(ret < 0){
        printf("[-]Error in connection.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("[+]Connected to Server.\n");

    while(1){
        printf("Client: \t");
        scanf("%s", &buffer[0]);
        send(clientSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);

        if(strcmp(buffer, ":exit") == 0){
            close(clientSocket);
            printf("[-]Disconnected from server.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if(recv(clientSocket, buffer, 1024, 0) < 0){
            printf("[-]Error in receiving data.\n");
        }else{
            printf("Server: \t%s\n", buffer);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I change my server code to the following can anybody tell me how to reply to all clients?

```
//Example code: A simple server side code, which echos back the received message.
//Handle multiple socket connections with select and fd_set on Linux 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>   //strlen 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <errno.h> 
#include <unistd.h>   //close 
#include <arpa/inet.h>    //close 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <sys/time.h> //FD_SET, FD_ISSET, FD_ZERO macros 
     
#define TRUE   1 
#define FALSE  0 
#define PORT 8888 
     
int main(int argc , char *argv[])  
{  
    int opt = TRUE;  
    int master_socket , addrlen , new_socket , client_socket[30] , 
          max_clients = 30 , activity, i , valread , sd;  
    int max_sd;  
    struct sockaddr_in address;  
         
    char buffer[1025];  //data buffer of 1K 
         
    //set of socket descriptors 
    fd_set readfds;  
         
    //a message 
    char *message = "ECHO Daemon v1.0 \r\n";  
     
    //initialise all client_socket[] to 0 so not checked 
    for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)  
    {  
        client_socket[i] = 0;  
    }  
         
    //create a master socket 
    if( (master_socket = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0)) == 0)  
    {  
        perror("socket failed");  
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  
    }  
     
    //set master socket to allow multiple connections , 
    //this is just a good habit, it will work without this 
    if( setsockopt(master_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&opt, 
          sizeof(opt)) < 0 )  
    {  
        perror("setsockopt");  
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  
    }  
     
    //type of socket created 
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;  
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;  
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT );  
         
    //bind the socket to localhost port 8888 
    if (bind(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address))<0)  
    {  
        perror("bind failed");  
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  
    }  
    printf("Listener on port %d \n", PORT);  
         
    //try to specify maximum of 3 pending connections for the master socket 
    if (listen(master_socket, 3) < 0)  
    {  
        perror("listen");  
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  
    }  
         
    //accept the incoming connection 
    addrlen = sizeof(address);  
    puts("Waiting for connections ...");  
         
    while(TRUE)  
    {  
        //clear the socket set 
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);  
     
        //add master socket to set 
        FD_SET(master_socket, &readfds);  
        max_sd = master_socket;  
             
        //add child sockets to set 
        for ( i = 0 ; i < max_clients ; i++)  
        {  
            //socket descriptor 
            sd = client_socket[i];  
                 
            //if valid socket descriptor then add to read list 
            if(sd > 0)  
                FD_SET( sd , &readfds);  
                 
            //highest file descriptor number, need it for the select function 
            if(sd > max_sd)  
                max_sd = sd;  
        }  
     
        //wait for an activity on one of the sockets , timeout is NULL , 
        //so wait indefinitely 
        activity = select( max_sd + 1 , &readfds , NULL , NULL , NULL);  
       
        if ((activity < 0) && (errno!=EINTR))  
        {  
            printf("select error");  
        }  
             
        //If something happened on the master socket , 
        //then its an incoming connection 
        if (FD_ISSET(master_socket, &readfds))  
        {  
            if ((new_socket = accept(master_socket, 
                    (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)  
            {  
                perror("accept");  
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  
            }  
             
            //inform user of socket number - used in send and receive commands 
            printf("New connection , socket fd is %d , ip is : %s , port : %d 
                  \n" , new_socket , inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , ntohs
                  (address.sin_port));  
           
            //send new connection greeting message 
            if( send(new_socket, message, strlen(message), 0) != strlen(message) )  
            {  
                perror("send");  
            }  
                 
            puts("Welcome message sent successfully");  
                 
            //add new socket to array of sockets 
            for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)  
            {  
                //if position is empty 
                if( client_socket[i] == 0 )  
                {  
                    client_socket[i] = new_socket;  
                    printf("Adding to list of sockets as %d\n" , i);  
                         
                    break;  
                }  
            }  
        }  
             
        //else its some IO operation on some other socket
        for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)  
        {  
            sd = client_socket[i];  
                 
            if (FD_ISSET( sd , &readfds))  
            {  
                //Check if it was for closing , and also read the 
                //incoming message 
                if ((valread = read( sd , buffer, 1024)) == 0)  
                {  
                    //Somebody disconnected , get his details and print 
                    getpeername(sd , (struct sockaddr*)&address , \
                        (socklen_t*)&addrlen);  
                    printf("Host disconnected , ip %s , port %d \n" , 
                          inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , ntohs(address.sin_port));  
                         
                    //Close the socket and mark as 0 in list for reuse 
                    close( sd );  
                    client_socket[i] = 0;  
                }  
                     
                //Echo back the message that came in 
                else 
                {  
                    //set the string terminating NULL byte on the end 
                    //of the data read 
                    buffer[valread] = '\0';  
                    send(sd , buffer , strlen(buffer) , 0 );  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }  
         
    return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `fork()`, the child process effectively receives its own separate copy of the parent process's address-space.  Since the child process's address-space is separate and independent from that of its parent process, any subsequent changes to variables in the parent process's address space will not be seen by the child process.

Since your server is calling `fork()` for each new TCP connection that is received, that means that each new TCP connection is getting its own address-space that includes it and any already-accepted sockets, but will never include any sockets that are accepted on the server *after* that client's process was spawned.  That is likely why you aren't seeing all the file descriptors you expect in your `fds` array, when you iterate over it calling `send()`.

My advice is to simply get rid of the `fork()` call.  If you want to keep (and iterate over) a list of all connected clients' file-descriptors, then its much simpler to use a single-process model rather than a process-per-client model.  If you need to react to incoming input data from any of the clients, you can use non-blocking I/O and block instead inside [select()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) or [poll()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) until one of the file descriptors in your list has incoming data ready for you to read.

Comment: I have added a new server code here. Can you tell if one client sends a message then how to forward it to all clients? What should I change in the new server file ?